# ANT xml file loop, conditional write to other path

Tags: xml, ant, xmltask

I have a property file which is dynamic, an extract of this file might look like;

```
 user1=password1
 user2=password2
 user3=password3
```

And I have a xml file (which is also dynamic);

```
<users>
 <user>
 <name>user1</name>
 <credentials>i-need-a-new-password</credentials>
 </user>
 <user>
 <name>user2</name>
 <credentials>i-need-a-new-password</credentials>
 </user>
 <user>
 <name>user3</name>
 <credentials>i-need-a-new-password</credentials>
 </user>
</users>
```

I need to replace the password for each user found in the property, and has to be replaced in the corresponding user-tag. Please advise

Comment: Convert the XML file into an XSLT template, then use the ANT task to generate the desired output XML file. If you need something more complex consider embedding a scripting language in your build (for example groovy, which has excellent support for manipulating XML).

Comment: Cheers mate, creating a XSL file, and then using the output xml in my build.xml did the trick.